# PostgreSQL use Select return in function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, sql-function

I am trying to run a query like

```
select id from table where id = pseudo_encrypt(select last_value from id_seq)
```

..

```
select last_value from id_seq
```

returns 5 which is the correct result.  My question is how can I use it as function argument

The story is I am storing id of the table as encrypted value of id_seq.

So I need to get the result where id matches with encrypted one.

```
select last_value from id_seq
```

this query returns 
[image]

and the result I need is [image]

I guess I need to write a function but I am not good at Postgresql.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You should be using `nextval()` and `currval()` instead of querying the sequence directly.

Comment: select * from table where id = pseudo_encrypt(currval('id_seq'))

I tried above but it returned   ERROR: currval of sequence "id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
SQL state: 55000

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The query must have be like

```
select * from table where id = pseudo_encrypt(currval('id_seq'::regclass))
```

Thanks for your helps